# How to force an app to change language in iOS/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having a problem with make app change language immediately like [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/zalo-nhan-tin-kieu-moi/id579523206?mt=8).

I've found a lot of similar question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977816/how-to-force-an-ios-app-to-use-a-certain-localization) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad).

But, unfortunately, the related answers to these question don't work for me. I need my app change language immediately when I tap on an cell.

Any ideas? Thank in advance.

Comment: Do use XIB or STORYBOARD?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [manual language selection in an iOS-App (iPhone and iPad)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad)

Comment: @JanakLN: the second link of mine is your link. But I don't think it solve my problem. BTW, tks for your help :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that [this](https://github.com/rudensm/LocalizationSystem) will solve your problem.

I had the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33253285/ios-app-localization-depends-on-user-choice-in-app) problem 1 month ago.

You can follow [this](http://aggressive-mediocrity.blogspot.rs/2010/03/custom-localization-system-for-your.html) tutorial.

Example:

In your `.strings` file you put translation: `"hello" = "HOLA MUNDO";`

```
#import "LocalizationSystem.h"

LocalizationSetLanguage(@"Spanish");
CCLabel* label = [CCLabel labelWithString:AMLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World") fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:32];
```

**EDIT**: This is additional information as user asks in comment:
If you want to translate whole view where your language option is changed, I propose you to make method that will be called everytime you change language:

```
-(void)translateOnChoose {
self.label.text = AMLocalizedString(@"hello",@"Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Your answer becomes essentially empty the moment those links break. You should post at least an outline of the solution, and/or source code / pseudo code.

Comment: I've posted example code. Hope this is fine now. Thanks for hint.

Comment: But this way, how can I force my view controller to run viewDidLoad? (I put all my code in viewDidLoad). This solution just work when I put my code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Comment: You mean how to translate everything in that moment when you change your language in app? Well, you must get hands dirty and make method to translate everything it needs to be translated in that view.

Comment: Yes, I just get confused. Because the app I've mentioned can do that.

Comment: @Stefan: tks, I've thinked about something like delegate or NSNotificationCenter to solve my problem.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but be carefull with deallon of that notification. :) Best regards.

Comment: this no answer at all IMO

Comment: because you only a provide some link without any explanation even.. you then show some code that does.. use some other localize macro... -- the only way you could even get this is by reading the link and then.. who knows if it even correct/helpful/suited ... because I don't think though btw

Comment: I gave this kind of answer because asker said he knows this way, just don't know how to forse app to translate that view where language selection is presented.

Answer (score 4):

My solution

First you need to create the String File

```
Go to Project Right Click.
New File->iOS
Under iOS you can see the Resource
Click Resource and you can see the String File among the group of files.
Click that give name whatever you want.
```

Now you can create the string file below.

```
"Date"="Date";

"Time"="Time";

"Done"="Done";

 "Back"="Back";
```

In appDelegate.h

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
  NSString *path;
  AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  if(app.currentLanguage==ENGLISH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==TAMIL)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ta-IN" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==SPANISH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"es" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==FRENCH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==JAPANESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ja" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==GERMAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"de" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==KOREAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ko" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==RUSSIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ru" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==HINDI)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hans" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==ITALIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"it" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==PORTUGUESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pt" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==THAI)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==MALAY)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ms" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==INDONESIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"id" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE1)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hant" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else
  {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
  }
  NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
  NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizeSTRING"];
  return str;
 }
```

Call this above method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of appDelegate.m

```
NSString *str=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] objectAtIndex:0];

if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"en"]])
{
    currentLanguage=ENGLISH;
    selectedrow=ENGLISH;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ta-IN"]])
{
    currentLanguage=TAMIL;
    selectedrow=TAMIL;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"es"]])
{
    currentLanguage=SPANISH;
    selectedrow=SPANISH;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"fr"]])
{
    currentLanguage=FRENCH;
    selectedrow=FRENCH;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ja"]])
{
    currentLanguage=JAPANESE;
    selectedrow=JAPANESE;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"de"]])
{
    currentLanguage=GERMAN;
    selectedrow=GERMAN;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ko"]])
{
    currentLanguage=KOREAN;
    selectedrow=KOREAN;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ru"]])
{
    currentLanguage=RUSSIAN;
    selectedrow=RUSSIAN;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"hi"]])
{
    currentLanguage=HINDI;
    selectedrow=HINDI;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"zh-Hans"]])
{
    currentLanguage=CHINESE;
    selectedrow=CHINESE;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"it"]])
{
    currentLanguage=ITALIAN;
    selectedrow=ITALIAN;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"pt"]])
{
    currentLanguage=PORTUGUESE;
    selectedrow=PORTUGUESE;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"th"]])
{
    currentLanguage=THAI;
    selectedrow=THAI;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"ms"]])
{
    currentLanguage=MALAY;
    selectedrow=MALAY;
}
else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"id"]])
{
    currentLanguage=INDONESIAN;
    selectedrow=INDONESIAN;
}

else if([str isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"zh-Hant"]])
{
    currentLanguage=CHINESE1;
    selectedrow=CHINESE1;
}

[self languageSelectedStringForKey:str];
```

Then in your Required View Controller

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{
  app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
  if(app.currentLanguage==ENGLISH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==TAMIL)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ta-IN" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==SPANISH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"es" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==FRENCH)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==JAPANESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ja" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==GERMAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"de" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==KOREAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ko" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==RUSSIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ru" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==HINDI)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hi" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hans" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==ITALIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"it" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==PORTUGUESE)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pt" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==THAI)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"th" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==MALAY)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ms" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==INDONESIAN)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"id" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else if(app.currentLanguage==CHINESE1)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"zh-Hant" ofType:@"lproj"];
  else
  {
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
  }
  NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
  NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:@"LocalizeSTRING"];
  return str;
}
```

Call this above method in your viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear method or Call that method where you want to call

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  //If you want to set language in label,TextFiled
  localizeBackLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Back"];
  localizeDoneLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Done"];
  localizeTimeLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Time"];
  localizeDateLabel.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Date"];

  //If you want to set language in button
  [yourButton setTitle:[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Back"]; forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [yourButton setTitle:[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Done"]; forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   //If you want to set the Language in cell     
   cell.labelHomeList.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Date"];
   cell.labelHomeList.text=[self languageSelectedStringForKey:@"Time"];
}
```

Finally if you want to change the language to other language.For example in (Settings) table you have two languages.If you want to change it to other languages please follow the below coding

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
   AppDelegate *app=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
   app.selectedrow=indexPath.row;
   if (indexPath.row==0)
   {
     app.currentLanguage=ENGLISH;
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
      NSLog(@"%d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]);
    }
    else 
    {
      app.currentLanguage=CHINESE1;
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zh-Hant", nil]forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

it works perfectly.

Comment: I wanted to do exactly that one month ago. :) Nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

use `reloadData`.

```
[YourUITableView reloadData];
```

and don't forget to save your language in a `NSUserDefaults`,

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:lang forKey:LANG];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

so you can load your views and storyboards accordingly because when your tableView is reloaded, you can add your check for language to display the correct view in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath method`.

**Edit.....**

If you want to use NSNotification, register your observer in your viewDidLoad, as this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                      selector:@selector(updateLanguage:)
                                             name:@"updateLanguageObserver"
                                           object:nil];
```

and in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` add the listener

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateLanguageObserver" object:self userInfo:nil];
```

which will call your method `updateLanguage` where you can handle your localization and tableView reloading.

and don't forget in the viewController that adds the listener to remove observer as such

```
 - (void)dealloc {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
 }
```

Comment: I've already do this, but I think there a better way like NSNotification or delegate. BTW, thank for your help :)

Comment: I added some info in my answer for NSNotification. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this once : [HERE](https://github.com/maximbilan/ios_language_manager)