# Change Region Format in the app programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I want to change the language and the **region format** within in the application. I can do something this to change the language.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zh_CN", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

Then quit the app using exit(0); once user changed the language.

[Change Language in the app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically)

But how can I change the region format to match the selected language? Is this doable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34130853/how-to-force-an-app-to-change-language-in-ios-objective-c/34131794#34131794

Comment: One question per post.

Answer (score 0):

**Change Language in the app programmatically. Or check it manually.**

```objc
NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
NSString* lan = [languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
    
NSLog(@"%@: %@ %@",lan, 
    [NSLocale canonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString:lan], 
    [ [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lan]
        displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:lan]
);
```

Comment: He asked region(locale) not Language.